# How to submit MapRecude job with jar not by terminal? (programmatically)

Tags: api, rest, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Hortonworks (using yarn, hadoop 2.6) and trying to study how to submit MapReduce, but I don't want to do it using terminal commands, I want to do it programmatically.
I want to write external java program to run the MR jar.

I looked here: 
[Cluster_Applications_API(Submit_Application)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_APISubmit_Application)

I see there is a need to get a new application id:

[Cluster_New_Application_API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_New_Application_API)

But when I use what they describe: "_http://[my host ip]:[port=8088]/ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application"
I get exception:

```
<RemoteException>
<exception>WebApplicationException</exception>
<javaClassName>javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException</javaClassName>
</RemoteException>
```

Am I missing something?
Does anyone have a REST example code for submitting and monitoring MR jobs?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate - [How can I run mapreduce job by Hadoop 2.5.1 Rest api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657874/how-can-i-run-mapreduce-job-by-hadoop-2-5-1-rest-api/27808843#27808843)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exactly answers your question - but you can try running the job from a bash script, and implement whatever automatic logic you want to kick off the job, using bash.
If using java is crucial, you can call the script you created (which runs the job) from java externally as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same. Found that it's http request issue.
Ensure that 
- you are using POST 
- and header has Accept: application/xml

Later, you may also need Content-Type: application/xml or Content-Type: application/json